# Parallel Algorithm for Data Averaging

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, lists, dictionaries

I am trying to write an efficient Parallelised algorithm for Data Averaging. By this I mean I have a list of tuples (K, V1, V2, V3) and in the end, I want a dictionary mapping K to the average of all V1, V2 and V3 present in the list with K.

If anyone can think of something it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Harris Mirza

Answer (score 1):

The role of three values $V_1, V_2$ and $V_3$ isn't clear for me, but anyway:

- Step 1. Sort the original list **in parallel** by key $K$ - you'll get a list of records $(K, V_1, V_2, V_2)$, where all the records with the same key are stored together in "buckets".
- Step 2. Process each bucket concurrently, calculating all the averages.

There are many parallel sorting algorithms, you can choose one depending on your computational model.